# How to select child records with include

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

Hi using Sqlite for mobile app with xamarin.  I am used to EF with SQL where I can automatically get child tables with .Include(), something like this:

```
Set<MyParent>(x => x.Id == id).Include(y => y.MyChild);
```

Can I do something similar with Sqlite?  I don't see anything like this on SQLiteConnection.

Also, another variable is that I choose to NOT clutter up my entity objects with Sqlite attributes - I am populating objects like this:

```
_sqlLiteConnection.Query<MyParent>($"select * from MyParents");
```

thanks.

Comment: as far as I know, there are no Constraints in SQLite.
what I did for something like this is that I get the children
and assign their value to each parent  
after checking if the parent id of the child matches the parent id
lazy but works

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLite provider for EF Core. [MSDN: SQLite EF Core Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

If you don't want to use it just try Join operation: [MSDN: LINQ Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8)